# backbone read/edit views based on user group

Tags: backbone.js

I have created a simple backbone app, which works well. 
Now I need to solve a problem, that I'm having trouble with. So I seek advice.

I need to represent my models/collections read-only or editable,on a per user/group basis.

My initial thought was, create two templates (read and edit) and their respective views. (psuedo-code):

```
var appRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
       '' : 'schedule',
  }
  schedule: function() {
    this.collection = new Collection();
    this.collection.fetch({success:function(resp) {
                                   if (resp.group == 'allowedToEdit')
                                     myview = new editView(this.collection);
                                   else 
                                     myview = new readView(this.collection);
                                   }});
});
```

This approach winds up with me having to duplicate templates:

```
<script type="text/template" id="edit-template">
  <div class="myclass">
    <input class="fn" type="text" value="<%= (fn) != '' ? fn : 'default' %>">
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="static-template">
  <div class="myclass">
    <div class="fn"><%= fn %></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Would it be better to in-line javascript for selecting an `input` or `div` tag instead or perhaps there is a better solution I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

I created a user model that contains user preferences and boolean values (returned from the database based on user permissions) if a user is allowed to edit or not.

The resulting code is:

```
var appRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
     '' : 'schedule',
  }
  schedule: function() {
    this.collection = new Collection();
    this.collection.fetch({
      success:function(resp) {
        myview = user.schedule() ? new editView(this.collection)
                                 : new readView(this.collection);
        myview.render();
    }});
 });
```

The function `user.schedule()` just returns the boolean value that is associated with the requested route.

The permissions on the back-end are restricted by group - so if the user changes these boolean values manually
to access the editable page - they still don't have authorization on the back-end to manipulate data.

Also, in my case, the editable/static views are quite different so I created two separate templates.